# Is there a way to get the file operations of an apt or dpkg transaction?

Tags: apt, package-management, logs

For security system maintenance reasons I would very much like to know the filename of each and every file modified by an apt transaction.  Think:

```
?\> apt install foobar --trans-log-file=foobar.changes
...
?\> cat foobar.changes
added /bin/foobar
added /etc/foobar.conf
modified /etc/default/grub
removed /bin/baz
```

Given it's possible to get a log of all package changes out of apt, a way to get this from dpkg would be an inconvenient but acceptable workaround.

Is there a good way to do this without extensive script parsing?

Comment: you could also use something like sysdig or SystemTap to record what filenames are touched by a process, though chasing through forks and whatnot might be tricky

Comment: auditd, sysdig, snoopy...it all depends how much resources you are willing to spend.

Comment: The auditd tools are looking like a good genera purpose start.  The "autrace -r command", and "ausearch -p pid --raw | aureport -i -f" combo works pretty well, and stripping out the reads with grep would also trim away most of the library loads and stuff leaving temp files to find by the fact they don't exist.

Comment: After further testing strace may do a much better job given it's -f parameter. I jst don't know if the speed is acceptable yet. Testing with autrace broke on simple IO redirection.  Some sort of ausearch first system that set checkpoints could probably work 2 as long as you weren't worried about catching background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

we can find installation logs in below two files:

- /var/log/apt/term.log
- /var/log/apt/history.log

Comment: Neither of these appears detailed enough.  They are limited to package level operations.